# render HTML in angularJS 1.x

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates

I have a directive and I´m replacing IMG urls with img src to display images inline

```
function message($filter) {

    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',

        scope: {
            data: '='
        },

        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.data.content = scope.data.content.replace(/(https?:\/\/\S+(\.png|\.jpeg|\.jpg|\.gif))/g, "<img src='$1' alt=''>");
        },

        template: '<span>{{data.nickname}}:</span> {{data.content}}'

    };

    return directive;
}
```

but instead of seeing the image inline I´m seeing the HTML tag as text I´m investigating **$sce** but I´m not sure how to use it inside a directive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are closer!. You are right about working with [`ngSanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) module.

It basically allows you to write raw HTML in your template (using `ng-bind-html` directive). You need to include it in your page, and declare it as a dependency in your module like this:

```
<!-- HTML -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-sanitize/1.6.2/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

// JavaScript
angular.module("yourapp", ['ngSanitize']);
```

And then, bind your HTML content in a `div` (or whatever) using `ng-bind-html` directive like this:

```
template: '<span>{{data.nickname}}:</span> <div ng-bind-html="data.content"></div>'
```

Now, the raw HTML contents of `data.content` will be replaced as is in your directive's template. Here is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lyorLXdXgL4vN96Dv9hd?p=preview) for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

So, a more angular and safer way to do this is to not write html to the template directly. Instead, you can use curly brackets to put the image url in the template like this:

```
template: `
    <span>{{data.nickname}}:</span>
    <img ng-if="{{data.hasImage}}" src="{{data.url}}" alt="">
`
```

This preserves template/data separation.

The way you had it, you're putting yourself at risk of XSS. There's a reason angular makes you jump through hoops in order to put generated html in a template. If a user ever is able to upload an image with js in the url, your site could be hacked. Angular's normal templating prevents this kind of attack automatically.

If you need multiple images, you can put add a url property to each object in your data, put the data array on the scope, then use ng-repeat to render the array of objects.

Comment: as you can see the tag img is created only if there´s a url that ends in one of the defined image extensions

Comment: You're right, I've updated my answer to use an ng-if in the template, and I added a "hasImage" property. I also added an explanation for why it's better not to do html templating yourself in the js.